# Return table and item-list, but only table is displayed

Tags: theming

```
$build['table'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => array('A','B','C'),
  '#rows' => $items
);

$build['itemlist'] = theme_item_list(array(
  'items' => $products,
  'attributes' => array('id' => 'my-custom-listing','class' => 'custom-class another-custom-class'),
  'title' => "Bonieren:",
  'type' => 'ul',
  'container_id' => 'bonieren',
));

return $build;
```

Above is my code. The problem is that only the table is being shown on callback. Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are mixing render arrays and html, use for both table and itemlist the same:

```
$build['itemlist'] = array(
        '#theme' => 'item_list',
        '#type' => 'ul',
        '#items' => $products,
        ...,
);
```